# Converting osm file to shapefile (or data frame) in R

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, r, ggplot2

I was looking for a road shapefile for Australia today. I ended up going to [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/australia-oceania.html). Open Street Map has data in `.osm` format. But they do not have one in `.shp` for Australia.

If possible, I want to convert the `osm` files to `shapefiles` using R. I have searched around, but I have not found solutions yet. Is there any way to to this? Alternatively, is it possible to read osm files into R and convert the data to data frame so that I can draw figures using `ggplot2`?

I have achieved the following graphic of NZ using two shapefiles with `maptools`and `ggplot2`. Ideally, I want to produce a similar map of Australia.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do with the road files - just display them on a map, or some kind of analysis? Shapefiles have some limitations; you may be better off using another format!

Comment: @Simbamangu I want to initially display roads on a map. If not shapefile, what format do you recommend to use with R?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not an R solution, but [Quantum GIS (QGIS)](http://qgis.org/) is a great way to achieve what you want.

You can simply load the .osm file (Add Vector tool), right-click it in the Table of Contents and Save As ESRI Shapefile.

QGIS may crash with such a large extract, so to avoid this you can uses [OSM Tools](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) like the [OverPass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to download only what you need using bounding boxes.

The [OverPass-Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) Api is also available to obtain extracts, a short tutorial on that is [Here!](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/overpass-turbo/#use-overpass-turbo)

I ran a quick example based on highway=primary and highway=primary_link tags (The OSM Highway Tagging Scheme can be see [Here!](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Highway_tag_usage)) using the Wizard on Overpass-Turbo and the image below was the result for Victoria.

I then exported the data as GeoJSON, loaded that into QGIS then saved the result as a shape file. (The second image shows the lines and polys loaded into QGIS)

The other alternative is to download the PBF or OSM file for the area from GeoFabrik and subset the data by extracting the highway=* tags using [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis). If you wish to update yor data on a regular basis, then Osmosis would be the recommended way to proceed. If it is a one off extract, the Overpass would probably be easier, even though you have to do it in smaller bounding boxes because of memory limitations. You would just apply the same Overpass queries do different bounding boxes.

[image: Highway=Primary OverPass-Turbo Results]

[image: Exported GeoJSON loaded into QGIS]

Comment: Nat as simple as you think: the australia.osm.pbf is 195MB large (compressed), so I assume it will crash QGIS to load all data. I suggest to filter the desired road information with osmfilter or osmosis **before** feeding QGIS with the data.

Comment: @Andre, valid point, will update the answer appropriately!

Comment: Thank you very much letting me know another way to handle my task. I learned something new from you. Cheers.

Answer (score 13):

@jazzurro, you perfectly can do this with R, just look up osmar package! Read the osmar documentation (osmar.r-forge.r-project.org/RJpreprint.pdf). At pages 11 pp. you can find a detailed example for extracting roads/highways by the according tags for munich.osm! After pulling and extracting the data from a planet file for Australia you can convert to any format you wish!

## Edit:

As some commentators were complaining about lacking examples I'll post an example from the docs. IMHO it wouldn't be necessary to retype existing examples here, would it?

```
library(maptools)
library(osmar)
url <- "http://osmar.r-forge.r-project.org/"
file <- "muenchen.osm.gz"
download.file(sprintf("%s%s", url, file), file)
unzip("gzip -d muenchen.osm.gz") # gzip is linux only, on windows I unzipped this manually with 7zip!

src <- osmsource_osmosis(file = "muenchen.osm")
muc_bbox <- center_bbox(11.575278, 48.137222, 3000, 3000)
muc <- get_osm(muc_bbox, src)
muc
summary(muc)

hw_ids <- find(muc, way(tags(k == "highway")))
hw_ids <- find_down(muc, way(hw_ids))
hw <- subset(muc, ids = hw_ids)

plot(muc)
plot_ways(hw, add = TRUE, col = "green")

# convert to spatial object (SpatialLinesDataFrame)
# and save to whatever format you like..
hw_line <- as_sp(hw, "lines")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I have seen one or two posts related to the package. But I was not sure if the package can convert `.osm` files to data frame. Having a quick look, it seems there is no direct way to convert `.osm` files to data frame. Or is there?

Comment: Read the osmar documentation (http://osmar.r-forge.r-project.org/RJpreprint.pdf).. At pages 11 pp. you can find a detailed example for extracting roads/highways by the according tags for `munich.osm`! After pulling and extracting the data from a planet file for Australia you can convert to any format you wish! ps: removed the other link from the OP as this didn't address dealing with osm-files..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SS_Rebelious, It clearly does provide an answer. I don't know what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Kay To make this answer better, you could explain how to use the osmar package to obtain the desired results.

Comment: @Kay, some links and more detailed explanation would be of value ..

Comment: @Kay Do you know whether osmar already supports 64bit node numbers? I don't see any hint in the pdf supplied.

Comment: @AndreJoost, sorry I don't know it either.

Comment: @Kay Thank you very much for demonstrating the osmar package sample. I will have a look of it this weekend. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

OK, here comes the correct answer:

- Make sure that `rgdal` (version >= 1.0.4) is installed

  ```
  install.packages('rgdal')
  packageVersion('rgdal')

  [1] ‘1.0.4’
  ```
- Make sure that `gdal` (version >= 1.11.0) is installed

  ```
  library(rgdal)
  getGDALVersionInfo()

  [1] "GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10"
  ```
- Make sure that `gdal` is compiled with Expat/OSM and SQLite support:

  ```
  c('SQLite', 'OSM') %in% ogrDrivers()$name

  [1] TRUE TRUE
  ```
- Make sure that you know which layer you would like to save as shapefile:

  ```
  ogrListLayers('filename.osm.pbf')

  [1] "points" "lines" "multilinestrings" "multipolygons"
  attr(,"driver")
  [1] "OSM"
  attr(,"nlayers")
  [1] 4
  ```
- We are ready to go:

  ```
  osm <- readOGR('filename.osm.pbf', 'lines')
  writeOGR(osm, 'myshapedir', 'mylayer', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile')
  ```

Once you read the file via `readOGR`, follow [these guidelines](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles) to learn how to plot it with `ggplot2`.

Note that you can also read `.osm` files in XML format, just make sure that they are not compressed (i.e. extension is `.osm` not `.osm.bz2`) But try to use .osm.pbf file since they are much smaller.

Comment: fyi, latest compiled `rgdal` for windows for is 0.9-3 and returns `FALSE FALSE` for `c('SQLite', 'OSM') %in% ogrDrivers()$name`

Comment: For `rgdal` you can try the source package (http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rgdal_1.0-4.tar.gz) or oldrel binary (http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/rgdal_1.0-4.zip). About the `GDAL` windows binary, I don't know, you can file a bug report to `GDAL` project and request that Expat and SQLite support must be enabled in Windows `GDAL` binaries.

Comment: Or you can build it yourself using MinGW on Windows and enable Expat and SQLite: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingWithMinGW

Answer (score 1):

osm2shp.ru here you can download openstreetmap data in shapefiles format. Data divided by regions: North and South America, Australia and Oceania, Africa, Europa and Asia.61 layers for download. Data filtered by "Map Features" conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question with some good old answers.

Here an updated, full `R` solution using the packages `osmdata` to fetch the OSM data and `sf` to manage and save the geometry:

```r
# install.packages("osmdata")
library(osmdata)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.7.2, GDAL 2.4.2, PROJ 5.2.0
# Check the available features
osmdata::available_features() %>% head()
#> [1] "4wd only"  "abandoned" "abutters"  "access"    "addr"      "addr:city"
# In our case, we are interested in 'highway'
selected_feature = "highway"
# Check available tags for the selceted feature
osmdata::available_tags(selected_feature) %>% head()
#> [1] "bridleway"    "bus_guideway" "bus_stop"     "construction" "corridor"    
#> [6] "crossing"
# For simplicity,we are going to download all
selected_tags = osmdata::available_tags(selected_feature)
# Create the request for Overpass API
q = osmdata::getbb ("Baranduda",
           display_name_contains="Australia",
           # limit=1e04,
           format_out = "polygon") %>%
  osmdata::opq() %>%
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(selected_feature
                  ,selected_tags)
# Download the data
o = osmdata::osmdata_sf(q)
# Street geometry can be lines (roads) and polygons (loops, roundabouts, etc.)
# We are going to merge the two type of geometry
# converting polygons to linestrings
full_street = o$osm_polygons %>%
  sf::st_cast("LINESTRING", warn=FALSE) %>%
  rbind(o$osm_lines)

# Save the file (here in temporary file)
output_file = tempfile(fileext=".shp")
sf::st_write(full_street, output_file)
```

You will get a warning when you save the data, due to the fact that field names are abbreviated for the shapefile format.
I suggest you use a more up to date format such as `.gpkg`:

```
sf::st_write(full_street, "your-file-name.gpkg")
```

You can visualise the results with `mapview`:

```
mapview::mapview(full_street)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. It is always nice to revisit old questions and update with current solutions.